# How do I force 12-hour time format in a TextClock?

Tags: java, android

I have a TextClock in android that is supposed to be displaying the time from the system in 12-hour format only. The problem is it is displaying it in 24-hour format even when the system itself is displaying it in 12-hour format.
I have already used the **android:format12Hour="HH:mm:ss"** in my text view, but it seems to be completely ignoring this.

And I know android guidelines say to not overrride user's system setting, but this textclock is for an app that is specifically designed for mathematical calculations in oil drilling industry that need it displayed in 12-hour format.

Comment: I suspect that you cannot control whether `TextClock` is using 12-hour or 24-hour formatting, based on the API. You may need to just use a `TextView` and update it periodically yourself, using `postDelayed()` to get control every ~1 second and updating the `TextView` to the current time.

Comment: In java SimpleDateFormat HH = 24h, hh = 12h. You could try that.

Comment: Joop's solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Joop Eggen's solution worked.

```
In java SimpleDateFormat HH = 24h, hh = 12h
```

Not sure how I overlooked that. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, solved it like this:

```
  if (sharedPreferencesSingleton.getUserPreferences24HourMoodBoolean()){
        textClock.setFormat12Hour("HH:mm");
        textClock.setFormat24Hour("HH:mm");
    } else {
        textClock.setFormat24Hour("hh:mm a");
        textClock.setFormat12Hour("hh:mm a");
    }
```

This overides the format no matter what the default user setting is.

Answer (score 0):

`android:format12Hour` specifies format to be used when TextClock is using 12hrs mode but it does not enforce it:

> Specifies the formatting pattern used to show the time and/or date in 12-hour mode.

so if user's device is using 12hrs clock mode, then that format will be used, otherwise `android:format24Hour` is used.

> in oil drilling industry that need it displayed in 12-hour format.

Pardon my French, but that's usually pure BS. How time calculations are affected by the way **you display it**? Regardless of what clock mode user uses your result will be the same. If not, then your app is broken an that should be fixed.

**EDIT**

`TextClock` is pretty simple widget. If current implementation does not fit your needs, write your own. You can even reuse current code [TextClock.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java)

Comment: Because the time format needs to display seconds (default android clock in status bar does not show seconds) and then the user puts the time in HH:MM:SS format into a handheld drilling terminal. The drilling terminal only accepts 12-hour format.

This is a private app for my industry and for our employees so yes we are going to force the way the the textclock is displayed. Your response is a bit rude.